# How to load a package in Maple?

Tags: maple

I want to use a package called "ESC" elliptic surface calculator that can be uploaded with Maple.

The instructions from the creator are:

> Save as a text file with character encoding ISO-8859-1 (ISO Latin 1)
>   and load within Maple using "read" command).

I have problem with uploading to Maple and saving with this encoding. Can anybody say the exact upload command with details and how to save text with this encoding?

Here is the package page: http://c-faculty.chuo-u.ac.jp/~kuwata/2012-13/Maple_resources/ESC.mpl

I use Windows 8.1 and Maple 18. Thanks!

Comment: Use several paragraphs instead of writing everything in the same paragraph. Use formatting accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the webpage, just right click on the source code file and then click save as a text file. 
After that, open maple work sheet and read the file `ESC.mpl.txt`, like this

```
restart:
read("C:/tcdata/ESC.mpl.txt") # I have save the file in a folder named `tcdata` in drive C.
```

Once the file is loaded/read in maple, you can do whatever you are suppose to do. I tried these, to check whether the source code is working or not.

```
ESC();
```

[image]

```
elliptic_surface(1,1,1,1,1);
```

[image]

Apparently, the source file has been read and is working properly.

Comment: I also want to run a package in maple that is on the webpage :
http://www.math.mcgill.ca/connell/public/apecs/Apecs6/
it's name is APECS and i think it's for linux 
Can anybody say that is it possible to run it on maple in windows 8.1 or not?
if yes , how?
thanks to any answer

Comment: @user371596 The same as I already told. In this case you have to read four files in to maple.

Comment: Excuse me . what are exactly this four file. i see more than it

Comment: @user371596 `apecs` `biraF` `f` `legen`

Comment: @user371596 you can thank him by accepting his answer and when you get enough reputation to upvote, you can also do that. :)

Comment: i accepted the answer!. i uploaded these 4 files on maple but it say again can't read so i can't use Apecs correctly