# error when uploading a package in maple

Tags: maple

I want to upload a package called "APECS" on maple , but when i do it, it sends me an error:" Error, (in with) package numtheory does not export isolve" and  "Error, unable to read `biraF` or `legen` or `f` or `cat` " but when i upolad them , the problem is still there. how can i fix this problem. plus, i should say this package is written in maple 6 and 5 ( respectively APECS 6 and APECS 5) but i have maple 2015 on win 8.1 on laptop, so please tell me can i fix this problem on maple 2015 , or give me an alternative way like how to change setting to maple 5 or 6, or finally how to get maple 5,6 if it is necessary
the official website for this package is :
http://www.math.mcgill.ca/connell/public/apecs/
i downloaded APECS.tar.z then extract it and then uploded. what's wrong?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried contacting the original author? Ian Connell @ McGill University?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a package in Maple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191128/how-to-load-a-package-in-maple)

Comment: yes. but he said he is working to fix it for new maples but it takes long time .please help me to get maple 6 or 5 . how should i do it?

Comment: No. it''s not a duplicate . it is totaly different. it is an internal error that is not my fault